# Node.js: synchronous file download queue

Tags: node.js, download, synchronous

Using [async queues](https://npmjs.org/package/async#queue) enabled me to add download tasks to a queue with a given concurrency.

The current problem: the tasks start an asynchronous file download, so the task has "run" after starting the download, not after finishing. This breaks the concurrency mechanism.

Now i'd like to create a download task (writing the content behind a URL into a given local file path) that works completely synchronously, so that the requests in the tasks added to the queue don't exceed the given concurrency.

Any library and approach is welcome.
Code should focus only on file download from given url to given path - no path creation, error handling etc.

Comment: "*so that the requests in the tasks added to the queue don't exceed the given concurrency*" How are you using `async.queue()` currently? The tasks shouldn't be exceeding the `concurrency`. Also, do you really need them to be synchronous or just [serial](https://npmjs.org/package/async#series)?

Comment: Currently I push 1000 tasks to the queue and set a concurrency of 20, because 20 downloads should run simultaneously. I update the question to be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your async workers, you can try this approach. Async queue have workers less than or equal to concurrency and a waiting queue with helper events/functions. So :

- Don't add all the urls/tasks to your async queue. Maintain a separate queue for them.
- When starting pop tasks equal to concurrency you want and add to async queue with async queue's **push** method. Also run functions for their start trigger.
- Your async queue is running with max concurrency now. Send an extra task which will go into waiting queue.
- Wait for **emtpy** event and run the added extra tasks start trigger using event handler. Also pop another task from your queue and add it to async queue.